# Change mysql system variable without restart

Tags: mysql, windows

Is there any way to change value of "skip_name_resolve" variable on windows mysql server without restarting service?

This variable is not dynamic, and cannot be changed with SET query:

```
mysql> set global skip_name_resolve="ON";
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'skip_name_resolve' is a read only variable
```

Answer (score -2):

> The MySQL server maintains many system variables that indicate how it
>   is configured. Section 5.1.4, “Server System Variables”, describes the
>   meaning of these variables. Each system variable has a default value.
>   System variables can be set at server startup using options on the
>   command line or in an option file. **Most of them can be changed
>   dynamically while the server is running by means of the SET statement**,
>   which enables you to modify operation of the server without having to
>   stop and restart it. You can refer to system variable values in
>   expressions.

this is taken from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html
ideally you should be able to change a variable by just using SET query.

Comment: No, this variable is not dynamic, and cannot be changed with SET query.

Comment: mysql> set global skip_name_resolve="ON";
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'skip_name_resolve' is a read only variable

Comment: So if it isn't dynamic you can't change it dynamically.

Comment: that's right @drull , its not dynamic http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve  I just cited the fact that if its dynamic it can be changed otherwise can't be. buddy any specific reason that pushed you to change this variable